# mvc4 System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting this error below.

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

the exception is triggered below in the SUBSTRING() function

```
<td class="hidden-desktop">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isim.Substring(0,10).ToString());</td>
<td class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.isim)</td>
```

I am trying to diisplay the short and long versions of the same text according to the screen size. what am I doing wrong to get the error message? or how should I use the substring() properly?

Comment: Html.DisplayFor expects a member (property or field) from your model and Substring is not a member of your model. You likely will need to add a property, say ShortISIM, that returns the shorter version of the string you want to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
<td class="hidden-desktop">@Html.Display("isim", item.isim.Substring(0,10))</td>
```

`DisplayFor` expect the argument to be property but `Substring()` is not a property

Or just

```
<td class="hidden-desktop">@item.isim.Substring(0,10)</td>
```

Comment: use the instance of the object you were trying to access (e.g. `item`)I think you are in a foreach. Model might refer to another object on your page

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use Html.DisplayFor for a simple string Property. Replace your code with the following:

```
<td class="hidden-desktop">@item.isim.Substring(0,10)</td>
<td class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet">@item.isim</td>
```

The other and better option is to define a new isimShort Property in your View Model, and set it to isim.Substring(0,10) in your Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this:

```
<td class="hidden-desktop">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.isim.Substring(0,10).ToString());</td>
<td class="hidden-phone hidden-tablet">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.isim)</td>
```